# Peano axioms expressed in type theory

Tags: peano-axioms, type-theory

I have a very strong understanding of 1st order logic and am trying to lean type theory as an alternative.  Could someone express the Peano axioms with type-theory?  I am especially interested to see how induction is represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\bot$ be the uninhabited type of kind $*$, and let the types

- $\mathtt{Zero}$ be of kind $*$,
- $\mathtt{Nat}$ and $\mathtt{S}$ be of kind $* \to *$,
- $\mathtt{Eq}$ be of kind $* \to * \to *$.

Then the Peano axioms can be formalized in type theory by saying that the following types are inhabited (in the format $\mathtt{inhabitant} : \mathtt{type}$, any free variables are quantified universally):

\begin{align}
\newcommand{\Zero}{\mathtt{Zero}}
\newcommand{\zero}{\mathtt{zero}}
\newcommand{\pa}[1]{\mathtt{pa}_{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Nat}[1]{(\mathtt{Nat}\ #1)}
\newcommand{\Eq}[2]{(\mathtt{Eq}\ #1\ #2)}
\newcommand{\S}[1]{(\mathtt{S}\ #1)}
\newcommand{\T}[1]{(\mathtt{T}\ #1)}
\newcommand{\Plus}[2]{(\mathtt{Plus}\ #1\ #2)}
\newcommand{\plus}[1]{\mathtt{plus}_{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Comm}[1]{(\mathtt{Comm}\ #1)}
\zero &: \Zero \\
\pa1 &: \Nat{\Zero} \\
\pa2 &:\Nat{x} \to \Eq{x}{x} \\
\pa3 &: \Nat{x} \to \Nat{y} \to \Eq{x}{y} \to \Eq{y}{x} \\
\pa4 &: \Nat{x} \to \Nat{y} \to \Nat{z} \to \Eq{x}{y} \to \Eq{y}{z} \to \Eq{x}{z} \\
\pa5 &: \Nat{x} \to \Eq{x}{y} \to \Nat{y} \\
\pa6 &: \Nat{x} \to \Nat{\S{x}} \\
\pa7 &: \Nat{x} \to \Eq{\S{x}}{\Zero} \to \bot \\
\pa8 &: \Nat{x} \to \Nat{y} \to \Eq{\S{x}}{\S{y}} \to \Eq{x}{y} \\
\end{align}

and also, for any type $\mathtt{T}$ of kind $\mathtt{T} : * \to *$ the following type is also inhabited:
$$
\pa{T} : \T{\Zero} \to (\Nat{x} \to \T{x} \to \T{\S{x}}) \to \Nat{y} \to \T{y}.
$$

Those are Peano axioms as in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), but I think there also should be something implying that $\mathtt{S}$ is a function (with respect to $\mathtt{Eq}$) instead of any relation, that is:

$$f : \Nat{x} \to \Nat{y} \to \Eq{x}{y} \to \Eq{\S{x}}{\S{y}}.$$

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: does this mean "4" has type "$* \to * \to * \to * \to *$" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "4"?

Comment: the natural number 4 as described by this formulation, s(s(s(s(0))))

Comment: 0 is of kind $*$ and $s$ is of kind $* \to *$ so $s(0)$ is of kind $*$ and so $s(s(0))$ is of kind $*$ etc.

Comment: I'm not getting this as much as I thought I did.  How would you prove 4 is a nateral number using the inference rule of type theory? I understand that you would need to show that a type is inhabited, but what type? (Is Nat Nat Nat Nat 0 a type in this formulation?) I didn't think it was standard to build types like that.  I am confused, thanks.

Comment: Here, $x$ is a natural number iff $Nat\ x$ is inhabited. To prove that 4 is a natural number you would like to prove that $Nat\ (S\ (S\ (S\ (S\ Zero))))$ is inhabited. However, $(pa_5\ (pa_5\ (pa_5\ (pa_5\ pa_1))))$ is exactly of the type you need, i.e. the inhabitant you are looking for.

Comment: Oh so in this formulation zero is a type.  Also thanks for reading past my typo.  I haven't seen types built up with variables like that before (aside from the pair type), is this a shorthand for that?

Comment: That $Zero$ is a type is mentioned in the very first sentence :-P Types are not built up with variables, you combine variables into a bigger expression, and that expression has a type. For example, when $f : A \to B$ and $a : A$ then $f\ a : B$. It is exactly the same rule, only the types are more complicated. ;-)

Comment: Ahhh might have to write it out more explicitly to get it.  How would you express the successor axiom in that form?

Comment: Which one is that? Maybe you mean $pa_6$ or $pa_7$?

Comment: pa6 where the successor function is defined

Comment: @user833970 Right now, I have no idea what do you want. I have already defined $pa_6$ (and the successor is defined where I state that it is of kind $* \to *$, not in $pa_6$).

Comment: I'll break my confusion into a separate question.  Mostly I'm confused because in the formulations of type theory I'm reading there is nothing justifying variable (or quantification) in the types themselves.  Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Here is what was throwing me off http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350145/variables-in-types-in-type-theory . Thanks again for your posts!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8184/discussion-between-dtldarek-and-user833970)

Answer (score 0):

Professor Peter B. Andrews book "An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory" (2002) covers exactly this subject. He expresses the postulates like this. (I omit type symbols from variables and constants.)

$1.\ N\ 0$

$2.\ \forall x(N\ x\implies N\ (S \ x))$

$3.\ \forall p(p\ 0\ \land \forall x(N\ x\land p\ x\implies p\ (S\ x)))\implies \forall x (N\ x \implies p\ x)$

$4.\ \forall x(N\ x\implies S\ x \neq 0)$

$5.\ \forall x \forall y(N\ x\ \land\ N\ y\ \land\ S\ x = S\ y \implies x = y)$

Type theory is higher-order logic, and induction quantifies over predicates "p".

Comment: Also see the related discussion in William Farmer's article The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory (2007), section 5 "Categoricity".

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add

http://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Index.html

is a good resource that has a lot of Peano Arithmatic problems.